# Codemirror get all lines as array

Tags: codemirror

Is there a way in Codemirror to get all the lines in the editor, represented as an array? I know it is possible to iterate over each lines like so..

```
editor.eachLine(line => {
  // do something with line
})
```

..but I'm looking for a way to just get all the lines, something like `editor.allLines()` or something..

Answer (score 4):

With [`editor.getValue(separator)`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getValue) you can get all lines as a sting separated by the given separator - default is `"\n"`.

Then you can turn your previously generated string into an array with [`string.split(separator)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
function getAllLinesAsArray (codeMirror) {
    return codeMirror.getValue().split('\n')
}
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/quic5/pen/WLzJPx